# What does Hallowed Moonlight actually exile?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Hallowed Moonlight](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHallowed%20Moonlight%5d) reads:

> Until end of turn, if a creature would enter the battlefield and it wasn't cast, exile it instead.
>
> Draw a card.

This seems confusing, the creature was cast when it entered the battlefield. Unless this references tokens or something? Please clarify, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is a good response to, say, flicker effects. If a player wants to make creatures go to exile and come back to get enters-the-battlefield triggers again, you can cast this so that they don't get them at all! Hah! This also applies to tokens, of course, along with Put a...onto the battlefield effects, meld... The list goes on. This is a fantastic card.

Comment: This card doesn't affect Westvale Abbey at all, and "reveal-cards-until effects" is both oddly specific and not really relevant to the effect in question.

Comment: @murgatroid99 reveal-cards-until-you-get-a-creature-then-put-it-onto-the-battlefield-without-paying-its-mana-cost-even-if-it's-fricking-Emrakul? Yeah, that applies. I was, however, wrong about Westvale. Modifying now...

Comment: My point is that it's not the "revealing cards from your library" bit that's relevant to the question, it's the "put the creature onto the battlefield" part. There are several other effects that reveal cards and do other things with them, and there are many other cards that put creature cards directly into play in other ways. That's why I said that your particular category, in which about 8 total cards are relevant, was "oddly specific".